# Dissolve using ogr2ogr gives 'no such function: ST_union'

Tags: ogr2ogr, dissolve

I am trying to dissolve a shapefile using ogr2ogr but I am getting error *no such function: ST_union*:

**Command:**

> C:\ms4w>ogr2ogr "C:\output\test-dissolved.sh p" "C:\input\test.shp"
>   -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_union(geometry) FROM test "

**Error:**

> ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(SELECT ST_union(geometry) FROM test ):   no such function: ST_union

Comment: Your GDAL version is is probably compiled without Spatialite. You can test it with `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select spatialite_version() from test"` test.shp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should use **GUnion** instead of **ST_Union**, I tried it and it worked.

below is a list of all spatialite functions where it shows the ST & GEOS functions:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html

Comment: 2.4 is a very old version with some security issues. I suggest upgrading...

Comment: You referred to 2.4 reference link in your answer. Probably just a google hit. http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html is current as of Aug 2016.